# Calculate Estimation Time Row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have been trying to solve this issue but my "Oriented Language" mind is not letting me figure out how to sum days in a SQL Query.

[image]

Basically i have in my database a table with the requests and which days the status of the request was Open, Pending or Closed.

I want to return a query that informs how many days the status was open and how many was pending.

The open days are calculated by the DATEDIFF between an open request and the moment the request moved to pending/closed. The pending requests are the DATEDIFF between the moment a request is moved to Pending and the moment is Open again.

I have been working in some solutions but have to be honest and say i'm not even close.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: You haven't given enough information in the question for us to provide an answer. Please read [Tips for asking a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2835541).

Comment: Chris, i showed the table i have and the query i want to return. What information you need more so i can provide it?

Comment: I add a brievy explanation on how the open and pending days are calculated, hope that helps.

Comment: Against what date are you checking how many days pending? open? is it against today?

Comment: Sam, Pending is the datediff between the moment the request was pending and the moment is open again. For example, the first pending was on 3/6/2016  and was open again on 5/6/2016. Which means is 2 days of pending time. That will add to the time of the second pending time.

Comment: Got it. What about Open Days?

Comment: If the request was open on day 1 and changed to Pending on day 3 means 2 days of open day to sum. Sorry i didn't made this clear in my question post.

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT  ID,
        [Request ID],
        [Status],
        CreationDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreationDate) as rn
FROM YourTable y
)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  c1.ID, 
            c1.[Status], 
            DATEDIFF(day,c1.CreationDate,c2.CreationDate) as [days]
    FROM cte c1
    LEFT JOIN cte c2
        ON c1.rn+1 = c2.rn AND c1.ID = c2.ID
    ) as p
PIVOT (
    SUM([days]) FOR  [Status] IN ([Open], [Pending])
) as pvt
```

Output:

```
ID      Open    Pending
GTGTG6  4       5
```

Comment: @LuísBaptistaLourenço I changed answer, now it will work if you got many IDs

Comment: gofr1, i'm getting the follow error: The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'cte'. Can you help? Thanks.

Comment: What columns do you have in this your table? Maybe you are joining two or more tables? Instead of `*` just list fields that you need to use if they have same name add `as SomeNewName`

Comment: Yes, i'm joining 3 diffrent tables because the status and request are in different tables. Is like this: http://i.imgur.com/GlAikf7.png   Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: gofr1, already changed and now is working but Open and Pending are NULL, i will give a better look at this. Thank you again one more time!

Comment: I add this to my answer, specify the columns instead of using `*`.

Comment: Strange... it worked well with given table you provided in question

Comment: I already changed and put the way you showed, thanks! Still getting NULL. I'm trying to see what can be, if doesn't macth the Name with Open/Pending or something similar. Again thank you :)

Comment: It means that somewhere there are NULLs in fields with dates, for example you may have ` row with Open or Pending and no more fields for same ID.

Comment: And there's a way of ignorning those fields?

Comment: Add 'where c1.days is not null and c2.days is not null' after left join

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that this will helpful for you since I don't have real data to test this,

```
SELECT ID,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS='OPEN' THEN DAY(CreationDate) END)- MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS='OPEN' THEN DAY(CreationDate) END)OPENDAYS,
   MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'CLOSE' THEN DAY(CreationDate)-1 END)- (MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING' THEN DAY(CreationDate) END)- MIN(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'PENDING' THEN DAY(CreationDate) END)) PENDINGDAYS            
FROM TABLENAME                   
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you Jay :) Gonna also see how this works for me!